# How do you set the conent of a Silverlight element to a view?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, telerik

I am updating some xaml I have written to instead use the code behind due to an issue cropping up.

`Pane` refers to a Telerik `RadPane` object.
What I need to do semantically is :

```
pane.Content = PaneView.xaml;
```

PaneView being a xaml file containing multiple elements and info. This will not work.

I had this working as follows in the previous xaml file, so it is possible to do; though I don't know how. Can anyone help ?

```
<UserControl x:vws="MyProject.ViewFolder.Views">
...

        <telerik:RadPane Header="PaneView" CanUserClose="False" CanFloat="False"
                                     telerik:RadDocking.SerializationTag="PaneView">
                        <vws:PaneView />
        </telerik:RadPane>
```

What wrapper do I need to put my xaml file in to force this to work?

Thanks very much

Comment: if you can access the object of your view you can pass it to Content. or else what you can do is read xaml using XamlReader.Load() for content loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RadPane control (the XAML) is defined as `x:Class="SomeNameSpaceHere.PaneView"` you can set the content pretty simply via:

```
pane.Content = new PaneView();
```

You can use a simple UserControl as a container:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeNameSpaceHere.PaneView">
  ...
</UserControl>
```